# Menu SearchView not recognized

Tags: android

It's not a duplicate, **AS WRITTEN IN MY QUESTION** I already tried thoes solutions and got the same error.

I have the following code:

**MainActivity**

```
   @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();

        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                search(query);
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String query) {
                //filterSearchFor(query);
                return true;
            }
        });
        return true;
    }
```

**menu/menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</menu>
```

I got this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                     Process: com.pgoiv.pokemongoiv, PID: 5336
                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.View android.view.MenuItem.getActionView()' on a null object reference
                                                                         at com.pgoiv.pokemongoiv.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:192)
                                                                         at
```

Tried few solutions of people who had the same error.. couldn't figure out what's wrong..

Seem likt `menu.findItem(R.id.search)` can't find my searchview although it's there as you can see in my xml file..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't insert **SearchView** into menu like this. Try this in your **menu.xml**:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```